# Trigger effect on one div when another div has 'bottom-in-view' using JS or jquery waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

I am using jquery waypoints(though I am happy to use JS).

I am trying to adjust the z-index or hide a div when a **different** div hits the offset 'bottom-in-view' (comes into view at the bottom of the viewport)

I can't do it on the element itself because it has a fixed position on the bottom already.

I've tried various things like setting the waypoint to trigger when the viewport is 50% down but it doesn't work.

Currently I am attemptinh this with waypoints and want this below, **except** I want the class 'custom-footer-z-index' to be applied to 'custom-footer' when '.pre-footer' is in view at the bottom not when 'custom-footer' is at the bottom

```
var $order = $('.custom-footer');

$order.waypoint(function (direction) {
   if (direction == 'down') {
   $order.addClass('custom-footer-z-index');
   } else {
   $order.removeClass('custom-footer-z-index');
   }

}, { offset:'bottom-in-view' });
```

Alternatively if this is not possible using waypoints, I am already using JQuery.

The reason I am changing the z-index is bring it in front of a header which also has a fixed position, so another option would be to hide the header once the section that proceeds it hits the top of the view port

The CSS

The header

```
  .effect-casing-yellow {
    background-color: #F7F3B0;
    position: fixed !important;
    top:104px;
}
```

The first div after each header

```
.vc_row.yellow.after-header.row-container {
    margin-top: 40vw;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

The rest

```
.pre-footer-z-index {
    z-index: 5;
}

.custom-footer-z-index {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Waypoints, but how about something like this:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('pre-footer'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    $('.custom-footer').addClass('custom-footer-z-index');
  },
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
})
```

When "pre-footer" is at the bottom, it'll add that class to `custom-footer`

Comment: Hi Max - Thank you very much - this seems to be working perfectly except I forgot to add that I need it to do the reverse when the user scrolls back up.

I had a go at it myself but it didn't work - Sorry I cant get the code in this comment to format properly.
`var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('pre-footer'),
  handler: function (direction) {
   if (direction == 'down') {
      $('.custom-footer').addClass('custom-footer-z-index');
      } else {
   $('.custom-footer').removeClass('custom-footer-z-index');
  },
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
})`

Comment: That seems right. Hmm.

I suggest putting a "debugging" statement inside the handler function, to see what happens when it's triggered.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not proficient in JS so I'm unsure how to do that. I only managed to put the other together by looking at other waypoints and trying to use some common sense

Comment: Ah I had just missed a closing bracket after the remove class line 
It should have been 2 curly brackets
`var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('pre-footer'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
    $('.custom-footer').addClass('custom-footer-z-index');
   }
   else {
    $('.custom-footer').removeClass('custom-footer-z-index');
    }

}, offset: 'bottom-in-view'

})`

Comment: I have awarded the bounty as it answered my original question

Comment: Glad I could help!